# button is not clickable in e2e

Tags: protractor, ionic2

i have a button with id="logout" in my app, when i use this id to click in protractor i get error

```
it('4 should click Log out', () => {    
         element.all(by.id('logOut')).click();
        browser.driver.sleep(5000);        
    });
```

my html is

```
<ion-buttons end>
        <button (click)='signOut()'>
            <ion-icon id="logOut"name="log-out"></ion-icon>
        </button>
    </ion-buttons>
```

my err in terminal is

```
should click Log out
      - Failed: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (1028, 28). Other element would receive the click: <button class="bar-button bar-button-default bar-button-icon-only">...</button>
  (Session info: chrome=50.0.2661.94)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.2 x86_64)
F
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are calling `element.all` on an ID?  ID's are unique, so you shouldn't need to use `.all`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I recently ran into a similar issue and the window size wasn't the problem rather it ended up being an overlay/backdrop problem. Not sure if this your problem but figured I'd throw it out there. Here is a [link](https://thecattlecrew.net/2015/03/05/automated-ui-tests-for-an-angularjs-material-select-item-with-protractor/) to the article for reference.

Adding a sleep (listed in the [Protractor API docs](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.sleep)) before searching got me moving after spinning my wheels. Finally got browser.wait after working through the flow.

```
it('4 should click Log out', () => {
    browser.sleep(1000);
    element(by.id('logOut')).click();        
});

-or-

var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var logoutButton = element(by.id('logOut'));
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(logoutButton), 5000);
logoutButton.click();
```

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Protractor is saying that it found the element with `id="logOut"`, but if it attempts to click on that element, something else at that screen location would be clicked instead (`button class="bar-button"`).

Look at your page visually and confirm that there is not something overlapping your logout button. Or maybe you need to put the id on the `<button>` element, instead of the icon, so protractor can click the right thing.

Note that this behavior may be different in chrome (which seems to be more strict about not being able to click overlapping elements) vs firefox (which can sometimes click elements that are below other elements).

Answer (score 0):

To add to @martin770's great explanation, there is an element that "hovers" the desired element that you want to click. I suspect this is because of the broken/resized layout of your application. Try *maximizing the browser window*, put this into `onPrepare()` in your config:

```
browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
```